# Best secure way to transfer virus from server to different location for investigation

Tags: malware, virus

I'm looking for a safe way to transfer a sample of a virus from an infected server to a laptop on a remote location, for further investigation.
Not sure how it's done in a proper way. Transfer via USB is not available...
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: zip it with encryption (a.k.a. password)

Answer (score 4):

The "industry standard" of transferring sensitive samples is to **encrypt the sample**. Then you can use any preferred way of transferring files like email. This also prevents antivirus products from detecting and possibly destroying the sample. An accessible and secure way of encrypting is to use a file archiver and set a password. Note that some email gateway antivirus products will try to unpack the archive by using a short password list.